# Grassmannian as a fiber bundle over $U(n)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, grassmannian

Grassmannnian is defined to be $U(n)/(U(k)\times U(n-k))=U(n) /H$, say. I have to show that the quotient map $q$ gives a fiber bundle. So, I have to get a map $\phi : U(n) \rightarrow Gr(k, \Bbb C)\times H $.  So it will be $A \mapsto (AH, h) $ where $h$ is a member of $H$. Now the question is what that $h$ should be.  Please help.

Comment: this fiber bundle will be _not trivial_

Comment: How should I give metric structure to Gr(k,C) defined in this way?

Comment: as a metric structure on the set of compact subspaces of fixed metric space (because all the fibers are compact)